# How do I convert an HTML page to a PDF using Classic ASP VBScript?

Tags: html, pdf, asp-classic, vbscript

There seems to be a lot of paid components out there and stuff for .Net, but are there any free ways to convert an HTML page into PDF using Classic ASP VBScript?  There has to be something from Adobe maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a few jobs involving this sort of stuff. ABCPDF from websupergoo is the only way to go if you ask me. They will give you a free licence if you link back to them and their kit is by far the best performing and easiest to use and setup that I've come across.

If you can I'd go with the .net version but they do a ASP version too. Can't fault them.

Its a tricky job to do it right though, you might have to amend your HTML pages to get them to look right as HTML is free flowing where as PDF's are per page. We tend to create seperate templates for ours or pass in a flag which appends a CSS class selector to the body tag which allows us to modify the page layout if being called from our PDF generator (ie don't fix a width, hide stuff you don't want rendered out, banners etc, search forms, change fonts, background images, etc.)

Comment: Just a side note...from experience...avoid ActivePDF at all costs and OmniPDF too...oh the pain.

Answer (score 2):

- If you can install custom components there's [AspPDF](http://www.asppdf.com/).
- If you can't install custom components [give FPDF a try](http://www.aspxnet.it/public/default.asp).

Comment: The link to FPDF provided no longer works.  Dead link.

Answer (score 0):

There's [ASPPDF](http://www.asppdf.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also install php (included even with most windows hosting plans) and use its included library http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php